# How do I query for subsets of a set in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do I query for all documents which have a subset of a given set in Rails?

For example, let's say I have `bars` which have a set of in-stock `ingredients` and `recipes` which have a set of required `ingredients`. Given a certain `bar`, I want to find all the `recipes` whose set of required `ingredients` is a subset of the `bar`'s in-stock `ingredients`.

The model definitions are as follows:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :recipes
```

Initially, I was trying something like:

```
@bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
@recipes = Bar.join(:ingredients).where('ingredients.id' => @bar.ingredients)
```

but this doesn't seem to work - I believe because the `where` clause with arrays translates to a SQL `IN` statement which just checks whether any of the ingredients are contained within the bar's set of ingredients.

Comment: do you have association setup for bar,ingredient and recipe model.If YES,then its easy :)

Comment: why don't you just do `@recipes = @bar.recipes`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your suggestions, @MohammadAbuShady and @Milind. There is a many-to-many relationship between `bars` and `ingredients` and between `ingredients` and `recipes`, but there is no direct relationship between `bars` and `recipes`, nor would `ingredient` be considered a simple through model that would enable the sort of `@bar.recipes` query you describe.

Comment: could you include the models definitions in the question